# What version of OpenSSL does the Poco library use?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, openssl, poco-libraries

I want to build NetSSL_OpenSSL and Crypto projected of poco library. I downloaded openssl in [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and add in my project. But when I build, I got LNK2019 error (the function just have prototype). So, what's exactly version of openssl Poco library used?

Comment: The `LNK` in `LNK2019` means its a linker error. Symbols are missing from an object file, archive, shared object or DLL in the case of Windows. You are likely not linking to something you should (your version of OpenSSL?) due to a path problem. We need to see a typical compile command (invocation of `cl.exe`), and the link command (invocation of `link.exe`).

Answer (score 1):

POCO NetSSL requires OpenSSL release **0.9.8** or later  (
[Poco Github - howtobuild.txt](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/dcdcee5afab6e8972f1b144ef7e7e884f85e83a3/NetSSL_OpenSSL/doc/howtobuild.txt) )